# When I input data and press the Add User button it will show 2 outputs instead of 1, what to do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[sample output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTNfV.png)
I need to show the information I collected from the inputs then show it in the table below.
It should show only 1 output and another if I press the "Add User" button again.
if I press the add user button it will show 2 copies of the output instead of 1. I only tried this code and tried checking if there is something wrong but I still cannot see the error.
this is the code:

```
<button onclick="collect()" id="submitBtn">Add User</button>
    <hr>
    <p align="center">By registering an account you agree to our <a href="#"><u>terms & privacy</u></a>.</p>
    <hr>
    <table align="center" id="display">
        <caption><b>Registered Users</b></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Contact Information</th>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click",collect);
    var row = 1;
    function collect() {
        var studid= document.getElementById("studid").value;
        var fname= document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var mname= document.getElementById("mname").value;
        var lname= document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var address= document.getElementById("address").value;
        var bday= document.getElementById("bday").value;
        var email= document.getElementById("email").value;

        if(!studid || !fname || !mname || !lname || !address || !bday || !email) {
            alert("Fill all the boxes");
            return;
        }

        var display= document.getElementById("display");
        var newRow= display.insertRow(row);

        var cell1=newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=newRow.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=newRow.insertCell(2);
        var cell4=newRow.insertCell(3);
        var cell5=newRow.insertCell(4);
        var cell6=newRow.insertCell(5);
        var cell7=newRow.insertCell(6);

        cell1.innerText = studid;
        cell2.innerText = fname;
        cell3.innerText = mname;
        cell4.innerText = lname;
        cell5.innerText = address;
        cell6.innerText = bday;
        cell7.innerText = email;

        row++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you need all of this code to demonstrate your problem?  You should generally try to reduce your code down to the minimum necessary to exhibit the problem.  Sometimes, while doing this, you'll discover the answer on your own. - Also, what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I can't see why you used the `Java` tag.

Comment: I am not big in `Javascript` but it looks like you call `collect()` twice. Once in `<button onclick="collect()" id="submitBtn">Add User</button>` and another at `submitBtn.addEventListener("click",collect);`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to replace the following statement:

```
var newRow= display.insertRow(row);
```

With

```
var newRow= display.insertRow(-1);
```

You may refer to the following page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow